# utf8 not showing hyphens correctly in echoed text

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

my MySQL database is set to utf8_unicode_ci and I have $pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"') as part of the following php code yet when I echo text from the query a hyphen - looks likes this â€“. What am I doing wrong, why is the hyphen not displaying correctly?

```
<?php    
    try {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=danville_tpf', 'danville_dan', 'password');
        $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $pdo->exec('SET NAMES "utf8"');
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $output = 'Unable to connect to the database server.';
        include 'output.html.php';
        exit();
    }

    $output = 'Theme Park Database initialized';
    //include 'output.html.php';//

    try {
        $park_id = $_GET['park_id'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM tpf_parks WHERE park_id = $park_id";
        $result = $pdo->query($query);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        $output = 'Unable to connect to the database server.';
        //include 'output.html.php';//
    }

    $output = 'Sucessfully pulled park';
    //include 'output.html.php';//

    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $parkdetails[] = array(
            'name' => $row['name'],
            'blurb' => $row['blurb'],
            'website' => $row['website'],
            'address' => $row['address'],
            'logo' => $row['logo']
        );    
    }
?>
```

Please help.

Comment: Hello ! Try to omit the characters founded before the <?php in the first line in your php file i think this is an encoding issue from the server you are working with :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`â€“` is common [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) for an [en dash](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) (`–`), which is a different character from a hyphen.

It is the result of taking the UTF-8–encoded form of the dash (`0xe2 0x80 0x93`) and incorrectly assuming that it is actually encoded using [Windows-1252](http://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/windows-1252/list.htm).

Interpreting those three bytes as Windows-1252: `0xe2`, `0x80` and `0x93` separately represent `â`, `€` and `“`.

Assuming the offending character is in the `blurb` field, if you query `SELECT HEX(blurb) FROM tpf_parks` (with a suitable WHERE clause), you will see the hex encoding of the offending bytes.

If you see `E28093` in there, then the database value is correctly encoded as UTF-8 and there will be a character encoding mismatch in your client or server configuration (e.g. you're reading it from the DB or displaying it to the browser with mismatched encodings).

If, however, you see `C3A2E282ACE2809C`, then the character has already been encoded incorrectly in the database — i.e. interpreted incorrectly, then saved as the UTF-8 representation of those 3 characters. If this is the case you'll need to update the data to fix the issue. You could do this using [`iconv`](http://php.net/function.iconv):

```
$fixedData = iconv("utf-8", "windows-1252", $badData);
```

This will convert the doubly-converted bytes back to the UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: Thank you so much for that in depth explanation. I'm a complete beginner with PHP/MySQL using a number of books as I build my site. This answer explained a lot about how encoding works and how to identify problems along the way. Turns out I was not using hyphens but en dash. So it was a problem with the data. Thank you.

Comment: Ah, cp-1252 problems... Haven't we all been there ;-)