# MariaDB query won't run via PHP, works manually with HeidiSQL; en dash encoding issue; proper DB utf8mb4 character set and collation

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, mariadb, utf8mb4

I'm importing emails from a Gmail account and storing them in a database. Apparently my PHP logic to convert everything to UTF-8 has failed with one particular email and when I run the query with that email I receive the following MariaDB error:

> Incorrect string value: '\x96 conv...'

Here is the minimized version of the SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO mail (subject) VALUES ('orkut – convite...');
```

I eventually tracked this down to a header subject string. In my general MariaDB query log the string appears as intended with the [en dash](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm) (`–`): `orkut – conv...`. When PHP attempts to run the query I get the error `Incorrect string value` as mentioned above however when I manually run the exact same query via HeidiSQL the query executes just fine!

The header is split between the key and value and then the value is processed as follows:

```
$p = explode(': ', $header, 2);
$s = mb_convert_encoding(trim($p[1]), 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($p[1]))
```

Now I've tried many things and the closest I could get was [cmbuckly's answer on another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15694543/606371) however using `$s = iconv('utf-8', 'windows-1252', $s);` did *not* resolve the problem in this circumstance. I have heaps of other attempts like using `utf8_encode($s)` afterwards though I'm just at a loss at this point.

- My MariaDB database has the proper `utf8mb4` character set and `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` database collation.
- I am *not* going to try to use MariaDB to encode/re-encode text, this is explicitly intended as a PHP question.

What is causing MariaDB to not work with the query via PHP though allows the query to work via HeidiSQL? Have I properly decoded the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/charset_support.htm

The only time an en-dash has a `0x96` byte in it is when a [windows cp125x encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page#Windows-125x_series) is used.

Figure out which one your source data uses and convert it to UTF8 with

```php
$utf8_data = mb_convert_encoding($data, 'UTF-8', 'cp125x');
```

Additionally: [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: This directly answers the question perfectly - thank you. The overall issue with no doubt likely extends to numerous other characters that when in a string causes PHP to fail to determine the proper character encoding so after much work I've put together a thread to help identify more troublesome characters so we can avoid data corruption: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70045981/list-of-known-troublesome-characters-that-causes-php-to-fail-to-detect-the-prope.